# Time ago plugin shows any moment now

Tags: jquery, html, timeago

Currently I am using timeago plugin to show the time ago. It had been implemented successfully. But there a little problem. When the page is loaded at first, it works properly and after some seconds it show `any moment now` in all place where it is used. Is this the problem with plugin or I am implementing in wrong way. Below are my code for implementation. If its problem of plugin please suggest me other time ago plugin that works perfectly and updates its time without page refresh.

### jquery

```
 $(window).load(function(){

 //timeago
   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
   jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
 //jQuery.timeago.settings.strings.inPast = "time has elapsed";
   jQuery.timeago.settings.allowPast = false;
 //timeago
```

});

### HTML

```
 <abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $noti->date_time; ?>"></abbr>
  //$noti->date_time is from database. eg: 2014-11-15 22:46:38
```

Comment: give an example of output of `$noti->date_time;`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery timeago accepts the time to be ISO8601 format.

try this:

for php 5.4+

```
echo (new DateTime($noti->date_time))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

for  < php 5.4

```
$date = new DateTime($ntoi->date_time);
echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: my php version is 5.4.12. I tried both but didnot worked. Thank you for support.

Comment: try `jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = false;`

Comment: If it is made false then i think this plugin is not able to communicate to its server for updating time ago. I made false and its not showing `any moment ago` but also its not updating time automatically in background.

Comment: i tried `jQuery.timeago.settings.allowPast = true;` and `jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;` and its working fine now. So the problem was not about date format. I had posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
   jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
   jQuery.timeago.settings.allowPast = true;
});
```